# Using the same table twice in a FROM clause

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
1 | 'Frank' | 'A'
2 | 'Frank' | 'B'
3 | 'Tom'   | 'A'
4 | 'Tom'   | 'B'
```

And I want an output that looks like this:

Frank | A | B


**Tom   | A | B**

I've come up with this:

```
SELECT N.Name, N.Surname, M.Surname
FROM NAMES N, NAMES M
WHERE N.Surname = 'B' AND M.Surname = 'A'
GROUP BY N.Name;
```

This seems to work, but I don't know if it is a good practise to use the same table twice in the FROM clause, or if the performance will be affected by this on large tables.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Try using code block (four spaces at start of line) for formatting table layout and query. Easier readability.

Comment: It is called FROM clause not FOR clause.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What happens if `5 | 'Ann' | 'A'` not `'B'` Do you want to skip this row?

Comment: Do you only have the case when you have to match two surnames? This approach doesn't work if you have more. And why not list them as rows and get them seperately for each name? It might get clearer if you give us more detail on how you are processing the data afterwards.

Comment: Hi, I tried to make it simpler with names and surnames.

This is for viewing different prices for a same product easily.

Like product 0000 has a price for retail and another one for stores. Maybe even a third one for many units.

I dont know if im explaining myself, english is not my primary language.

Comment: @top, The OP SQL sentence don't produces OP expected output.

Comment: Notice that in standard SQL, when you have a GROUP BY clause, columns that are not in the GROUP BY clause cannot appear in the SELECT clause unless aggregated. Although your DBMS allows it (others don't), it is bad practice.

Comment: have you tried SELECT distinct N.Name, N.Surname, N.Surname
FROM NAMES N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having more than one table behind `from` is old-fashioned: you can make your `join` more readable with the standard `on` syntax:

```
from    Names n
join    Names m
on      n.name = m.name
```

A self-join with a restrictive condition isn't too expensive.  And `Name` is a pretty restrictive condition: only 2 records will share the name.

You could write it a little bit more efficient in a database that supports `row_number()`.  That allows you to run the query without a `join`:

```
select  Name
,       max(case when rn = 1 then Surname end) as Surname1
,       max(case when rn = 2 then Surname end) as Surname2
,       max(case when rn = 3 then Surname end) as Surname3
from    (
        select  row_number() over(
                    partition by Name
                    order by Surname) as rn
        ,       Name
        ,       Surname
        from    YourTable
        ) SubQueryAlias
group by
        Name
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement it tomorrow, as its 2 am now, but it sounds good.